# What is the purpose of the Attack stat for a unit with no melee weapons?

Tags: warhammer-40k

According to the [8th Edition Core Rules](https://www.games-workshop.com/resources/PDF/40k/warhammer_40000_en.pdf), the attack stat is defined as follows:

> **Attacks (A):** This tells you how many times a model can strike blows in hand-to-hand combat.

As I understand, this only affects the fight phase, and as such only melee weapons. However, I see several units, such as the Kustom Boosta-Blastas, which have an attack stat, but no melee weapons. What is the purpose of this stat? Or is it just "filler"?

Comment: Do all models have an Attack stat? Are there any rules or abilities that interact with the stat? I'm not a 40k player, but if I were to guess I'd say it is forward planning, for example to cover cases where a unit that doesn't currently have melee options receives some in a future expansion.

Comment: Likewise, there are some models (like the Tau Ethereal on Hover Drone) that have a BS stat, but don't seem to have any way of taking a ranged weapon.

Comment: @QuestionMarks There are some fortifications that have weapons which can be fired by units that have "embarked" upon them.

Comment: @JamesOtter All models have a value for all stats, even if that is redundant. Move is maybe an exception, there are things which are totally immobile and have a printed move stat of -, presumably because a move of 0" would imply they could advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All models have a close combat weapon in addition to the listed equipment (described in page 183 of the 8th Edition Core Rule Book). It is Strength: User, AP: 0, Damage: 1.

I think this is supposed to represent fighters using their fists, guns as clubs, body slams and any small knives etc they carry.

Some people have been taking advantage of this for units (like helbrutes) that have a bonus for having two melee weapons. It also allows models with weapons like power fists (2x strength, good AP, -1 to hit rolls) to use a different attack against targets where the power fists abilities would be wasted.

Comment: It's page 183 of the Warhammer 40000 rulebook.